# How to install a package on Debian 8 Jessie running systemd without starting up the service?

Tags: debian, package-managers, systemd, package-management

I have ansible provisioning HAProxy and Nginx onto a Debian 8 running `systemd` in a Virtualbox VM.

The problem is that Nginx installation fails, because of a port conflict. HAProxy installs first and runs on port 80, the same port that Nginx's default tries to start on.

```
# apt-get install -y nginx-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  geoip-database libgeoip1 libxslt1.1 nginx-common
Suggested packages:
  geoip-bin fcgiwrap nginx-doc ssl-cert
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  geoip-database libgeoip1 libxslt1.1 nginx-common nginx-full
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,418 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,362 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libgeoip1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 55783 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgeoip1_1.6.2-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgeoip1:amd64 (1.6.2-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxslt1.1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxslt1.1_1.1.28-2+b2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxslt1.1:amd64 (1.1.28-2+b2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package geoip-database.
Preparing to unpack .../geoip-database_20150317-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking geoip-database (20150317-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nginx-common.
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-common_1.8.0-1~dotdeb+8.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-common (1.8.0-1~dotdeb+8.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nginx-full.
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-full_1.8.0-1~dotdeb+8.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-full (1.8.0-1~dotdeb+8.2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Setting up libgeoip1:amd64 (1.6.2-4) ...
Setting up libxslt1.1:amd64 (1.1.28-2+b2) ...
Setting up geoip-database (20150317-1) ...
Setting up nginx-common (1.8.0-1~dotdeb+8.2) ...
Setting up nginx-full (1.8.0-1~dotdeb+8.2) ...
Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-full (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-full
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
#
#
# systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2015-07-09 12:02:23 UTC; 10s ago

Jul 09 12:02:23 web1.dev nginx[2904]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: ... use)
Jul 09 12:02:23 web1.dev nginx[2904]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jul 09 12:02:23 web1.dev systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 09 12:02:23 web1.dev systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse prox...rver.
Jul 09 12:02:23 web1.dev systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

```

I've tried the following to install nginx without starting the service:

- setting RUN_LEVEL=1, but systemd doesn't use run levels.
  https://askubuntu.com/a/75560
- I tried creating the /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d file, but didn't work.
  https://serverfault.com/questions/567474/how-can-i-install-packages-without-starting-their-associated-services
  https://major.io/2014/06/26/install-debian-packages-without-starting-daemons/  and https://serverfault.com/questions/681588/prevent-apache-from-starting-after-apt-get-install
- I tried the root/fake, which worked, but I prefer something more elegant. https://askubuntu.com/questions/74061/install-packages-without-starting-background-processes-and-services

How can nginx (or any package) be installed on Debian 8 with systemd without automatically starting up the service?

Answer (score 0):

There is the yum module within Ansible:

**http://docs.ansible.com/yum_module.html**

For example, to install the latest version of Apache:

**yum: name=httpd state=latest**

Answer (score 0):

You can always *mask* services to prevent them from starting, even before installing packages. For nginx it would be:

```
systemctl mask nginx.service
```

To undo the above action and remove corresponding symlink under `/etc/systemd/system/` use:

```
systemctl unmask nginx.service
```